# C# - Can we set different color for each stacked of Stacked bar chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, stackedbarseries

Can we set different color for individual stacked of stacked bar chart or change the order of color in stacked bar charts bar for example

[image]

same as like this solution provided in python
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273196/stacked-bar-chart-with-differently-ordered-colors-using-matplotlib)

Any help will be very, very helpful. Thank you very much for your attention!

Comment: Which charting library are you using?

Comment: I working on MVC3 so that i am using System.Web.Helpers;

Comment: designwise, one would usually either put the thing measure reprented by the colour legend in the same order of occurance or  sort by size (e.g.  all largest values first)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

I assume you have 4 series and those series are A,B,C and D.

For changing the color, lets say A's, according to the Data 1,2,3,4 you could use;

```
Series sr = new Series();
sr.Name = "A";
sr.Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
sr.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar;
sr.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);

for (int i = 0 ; i < xValues.Lenght; i++) //xValues.Lenght = 4 in this case where you have 4 Data number
{ 
    if(i == 0) // Don't forget xValues[0] is Data4 in your case
        sr.Points[i].Color = Dr.Color.Black;
    else
        sr.Points[i].Color = Dr.Color.Yellow;
}
```

This will give someting like this; [image: Example of Output]